Two balls bouncing up and down, unevenly help
I have animated the first ball to bounce and it's looped in 20 frames.
I adding a second ball by just copying the first.
With the second ball I want it to bounce next to the original ball with the same animation.
I want the balls to have the same animation only different times so that they bounce unevenly.
I recognise that this is probably an easy fix but for hours I've failed to solve this mystery.
What I've tried:
Paste flipped don't work since I don't have bones I guess.
Scale to -1 won't do the trick either.
Manually placing the key frames where I think they should be not working. (The animation loop gets edgy).
How would I go by solving this mystery?
EDIT: Heres a video showcasing the balls, id like to keep it to 20 frames if possible.




Hello, could you please share your file (only the 2 balls)? It's not clear how you've made your balls bounce. You could simply push the action into the NLA and shift the strips?

How do i share my file here?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use workupload and share the link

i've uploaded a gif in the post

do they share the same action? you could duplicate the action or push it down into the NLA

Im currently in dope sheet and action editor, what now?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.


I want the balls to have the same animation only different times so that they bounce unevenly."

Assuming "different times" mean that one object's animation is the same but not happening at the same time, you can just select one object, then select all its keyframes and move them on the X axis in either the timeline/graph/dopesheet editor. Example:

If you meant one should bounce slower, then it means the spacing between keyframes on the X axis needs to be bigger. You can do that similarly as the above, but by scaling on the X axis instead of moving:


This means i need to stretch the frames beyond of what the loop needs and then place the keyframes of the second ball unevenly.
I thought i could achieve this with a simple 20 frame loop?

Go into the Dope Sheet, switch it to Action Editor, push down the action into the NLA, do it for both the 2 balls:

Open the Nonlinear Animation editor, and for one of your balls duplicate the strip and shift the 2 strips:


I got stuck on "shift the one you want:". How do i do that?

if i move them to the right, then it will be more then 20 frames, do you see my issue?

No, what do you mean by it will be more than 20 frames?

The first ball was created with 20 frames, to create a loop of a bouncing ball.
This means i have limited the amount of frames to 21 frames.
So for the second ball, if i copy the frames from the first and paste and then move the frames to the right for example to create an uneven time when the balls bounce on the ground, then  i need to increase the amount of frames, but even if i do so, it wont go smoothly as u might understand

i updated thee post with a picture do demonstrate my issue

@Kahvu I've edited my answer again, maybe it answers? You could also do it in the Dope Sheet directly but the NLA is convenient
